# Webpack encore include external js

Tags: symfony, webpack, symfony4, webpack-encore

I have a problem i can't understand :

webpack.config.js

```
Encore
    // directory where compiled assets will be stored
    .setOutputPath('public/build/')
    .copyFiles({
         from: './assets/media',
         // if versioning is enabled, add the file hash too
         to: 'media/[path][name].[hash:8].[ext]',
     })
    // public path used by the web server to access the output path
    .setPublicPath('/build')
    // only needed for CDN's or sub-directory deploy
    //.setManifestKeyPrefix('build/')


    .addEntry('app', ['./assets/js/app.js'])


    .splitEntryChunks()

    // will require an extra script tag for runtime.js
    // but, you probably want this, unless you're building a single-page app
    .enableSingleRuntimeChunk()
```

[...]
    ;

app.js

```
// require jQuery normally
const $ = require('jquery');

// create global $ and jQuery variables
global.$ = global.jQuery = $;

require('../../assets/vendors/general/jquery/dist/jquery.js');
require('../../assets/vendors/general/popper.js/dist/umd/popper.js');
require('../../assets/vendors/general/bootstrap/dist/js/bootstrap.min.js');
require('../../assets/vendors/general/js-cookie/src/js.cookie.js');
require('../../assets/vendors/general/tooltip.js/dist/umd/tooltip.min.js');
require('../../assets/vendors/general/perfect-scrollbar/dist/perfect-scrollbar.js');
require('../../assets/vendors/general/sticky-js/dist/sticky.min.js');
require('../../assets/vendors/general/wnumb/wNumb.js');
require('../../assets/js/demo1/scripts.bundle.js');

require('../../assets/css/demo1/style.bundle.css');
require('../../assets/css/demo1/skins/header/base/light.css');
require('../../assets/css/demo1/skins/header/menu/light.css');
require('../../assets/css/demo1/skins/brand/dark.css');
require('../../assets/css/demo1/skins/aside/dark.css');
```

But On my page i get this error :

> jquery.js:3850 Uncaught ReferenceError: PerfectScrollbar is not
>   defined

I don't understand why because perfect scrollbar is well required. Same thing if i do it with import. And same thing if i remove perfect scroll bar i got the same message with sticky js.

Thanks for your help,

Alex

Comment: I use it in exactly the same environment, and with similar `require` instruction, and it works fine. Though I'm not sure how you get "PerfectScrollbar" error -- that plugin adds `perfectScrollbar` (lowercase "p") function to `jQuery.fn`, so, to use it you need to call it like this: `$('.selector').perfectScrollbar(...)` (lowercase "p" again).

Comment: Yes but when i call the library directly in the html jt works fine. Its not working when i call it from webpack

Comment: Oh, I think I see, you include 2 versions of `jQuery` -- `require('jquery')` and `require('../../assets/vendors/general/jquery/dist/jquery.js')`, and second one might overwrite it for other plugins (that are loaded later). But you have reference to the first one, which does not have other plugins. So, remove second `jQuery` inclusion, I guess?

Comment: I remove the second require but i get the same problem :( I really don't understand. Maybe a problem of order? I think the library is included after the call. When i include the script in html it works fine.

Answer (score 0):

Ok found the solution with Metronic support :

```
Encore.addPlugin(new webpack.ProvidePlugin({
    PerfectScrollbar: require.resolve("perfect-scrollbar"),
}));
```